# When arithmetic operations overflow do they result in a deterministic figure?

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer-overflow, arithmetic-expressions

Given the same two inputs and an arithmetic operation that would result in an overflow is that overflowed result always going to be the same?

Just for background I'm working in a Visual Studio C++ project with some funky small floating point figures coming from some Gaussians being passed over from Matlab via calllib that are giving me what appears as overflow where the exponent jumps to huge numbers in certain places of this matrix. The trouble is when I rerun my code I still get overflows but in different places, which makes me wonder how stable and deterministic overflow behavior is.

Comment: From a language perspective, signed integer overflow results in undefined behavior. Thus, a particular implementation could provide deterministic behavior. But, a different implementation could pull rabbits out of a hat.

Comment: Very good to relate to a language perspective, I'll do some experimenting at the end of the day to see how visual c++ 2010 behaves for something like floatmax*floatmax and intmax+intmax.

Comment: You can blame your compiler or the machine but that never gets you anywhere.  Clearly the real problem is that the math model is completely broken and producing nonsensical results.

Comment: You ask about “arithmetic overflow” and you tag your question “floating-point” and “integer-overflow”? Make up your mind, then ask.

Comment: @PascalCuoq sorry but you may not realize the limited tags for use here. There was no tag for "arithmetic-overflow" nor was there one for "floating-point-overflow", and "overflow" alone related to some CSS stuff. I'm working with floating point values hence the floating-point tag. If you have the rep feel free to make some tags if you feel mine are cluttering up the used tags and I'll readily use them.

Comment: I guess another thing is what is there to make up my mind about, are not both integers and floating point data subject to overflow? I can do arithmetic in either so what's the issue/contradiction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overflow of signed integers is *undefined behavior*; anything could happen, even things like your program crashing.

As a practical matter, when the compiler built your program, it probably decided on some deterministic behavior...

... however, the thing you really have to worry about is that the compiler will decide upon some *other* deterministic behavior if you edit your program and compile it again, or you change the build options and compile it again, or if you upgrade to a newer version and compile it again, or if you try using a different compiler, or you use the same function in two different places and it decides to pick a different behavior for each one, and so forth.

Comment: That is a keen subtlety indeed! Never even considered such variability before. Thanks for sharing! As it turns out my indeterminateness is not related to the model or overflow but seems to be something with the connection between Matlab and C++. With a fresh instance of Matlab the results are correct, I run the matlab script again and get funky results, then again more different results. Close matlab reopen repeat, same story. I'm pretty boggled debugging over here but it was interesting to consider the behavior, or rather the undefined behavior of overflow as I wander about the problem space.

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer this exhaustively but thought I'd demo the small example I made.
So here's the toy example cooked up in Visual Studio 2010

```
#include <climits>
#include <cfloat>

int _tmain( int argc , _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    // IS OVERFLOW DETERMINISTIC
    int a = INT_MAX;
    int b = a + 10;

    std::cout <<"a="    << a << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"b=a+1="<< b << std::endl;

    double d1 = DBL_MAX ;
    double d2 = 2*d1;
    std::cout <<"d1="     << d1 << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"d2=2*d2="<< d2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And here's a few calls to the application...

```
C:\Users\me>cd/d C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestSolution\Debug

C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestSolution\Debug>TestSolution.exe
a=2147483647
b=a+10=-2147483639
d1=1.79769e+308
d2=2*d2=1.#INF

C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestSolution\Debug>TestSolution.exe
a=2147483647
b=a+10=-2147483639
d1=1.79769e+308
d2=2*d2=1.#INF

C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestSolution\Debug>TestSolution.exe
a=2147483647
b=a+10=-2147483639
d1=1.79769e+308
d2=2*d2=1.#INF

C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestSolution\Debug>TestSolution.exe
a=2147483647
b=a+10=-2147483639
d1=1.79769e+308
d2=2*d2=1.#INF
```